# Saving Image Using Awesomium

Tags: image, render, awesomium

I'm using Awesomium .NET 1.7.0.5 and am trying to retrieve an image element from page and save it into memory/disk. In the earlier versions, this can be achieved by calling webView.Render(). However I noticed they have removed this in the recent releases. Is there any workaround for this?

Note: I do not want to redownload the image, so retrieving the image URL then download it again is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
((BitmapSurface) view.Surface).SaveToPNG("c:\\temp\\Page.png");
```

Best