# getContext(2d) & drawImage > toDataURL > undefiend issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Here is the c# method and js function :

```
    public static string JsGetImgBase64String(Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl wb, string getElementQuery, bool leaveOnlyBase64Data = true)
    {
        string data = wb.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(@"
                                    function getImgBase64String(img)
                                    {
                                        alert(img.attr('src'));
                                        var cnv = document.createElement('CANVAS');
                                        var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
                                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                                        return cnv.toDataURL();
                                    }
                        " + String.Format("getImgBase64String({0});", getElementQuery));

        if (data == "undefined")
            return string.Empty;

        if (leaveOnlyBase64Data && data.Contains(","))
        {
            data = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(",") + 1);
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Here is that image :

```
@"$(""img[src$='/Appointment/ShowCaptchaImage']"")"
```

Here is that alert result :  `/Appointment/ShowCaptchaImage`

And here is the result(no error) of that function : `The return value of that function is undefiend`.

Now what is the problem?
How can i fix `undefiend` issue using with jquery or javascript?

---

Here is the c# call of that method?

```
string imgBase64 = JsGetImgBase64String(webControl_1, @"$(""img[src$='/Appointment/ShowCaptchaImage']"")");
byte[] imgBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imgBase64);
```

I have error on `byte[] imgBytes =`!

Comment: here is related thread :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654964/awesomium-how-save-a-loaded-image-without-redownload-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img.attr('src')` is a jquery function. Since that worked, you can safely assume you are using a jquery object.

`ctx.drawImage()` does not accept a jquery element.

Try to use `ctx.drawImage(img[0], 0, 0);` instead. Using `[0]` makes sure you get the actual DOM element and not the JQuery element.